# Failed to Execute DrawImage in Next.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, next.js

I'm new to Next.js. I'm trying to load image in html canvas and do some work on it.

When I try to draw on canvas I'm getting this error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.
```

This is my code

```
import Image from "next/image";

function tileImage() {
  return <Image src="/tiles.png" alt="tiles" />;
}
           
const draw = (ctx) => {
    for (var c = 0; c < map.cols; c++) {
      for (var r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
        var tile = map.getTile(c, r);
        if (tile !== 0) {
          // 0 => empty tile
          ctx.drawImage(
            tileImage, // image
            (tile - 1) * map.tsize, // source x
            0, // source y
            map.tsize, // source width
            map.tsize, // source height
            c * map.tsize, // target x
            r * map.tsize, // target y
            map.tsize, // target width
            map.tsize // target height
          );
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <Canvas draw={draw} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Next.js Image is not html img object but component, try use just <img/>

Comment: @Bzone  Still doesn't work. Same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, another idea: You passing function not img.
Try this:

```
const imgRef=useRef();

...
ctx.drawImage(
            imgRef.current, // image
            (tile - 1) * map.tsize, // source x

...
 <div className={styles.container}>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <Canvas draw={draw} />
        <img src="/tiles.png" alt="tiles" ref={imgRef}/>
      </main>
 </div>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with Next.js, and I solved it easily by writing **window** like this:-

```
...
const img = new window.Image();
img.src = '...';
img.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, myWidth, myHeight);
};
...
```